# Setting The Value Of An Input with Type File

Tags: html

So I have this code:

```
<input type="file">
```

I want to be able to set what the file is. I understand that this is not possible to set files that are stored on the user's computer. But I am trying to submit a file that is stored on the internet to a server-side script. So for my purposes, **Is there a way to set what file is in the input if the file is stored online rather than on the user's computer?** If not, **How can I read an online file with JavaScript?** Or **How can I submit an online file to a server-side script so that I can read it?**

Comment: nothing is 'online' (in the sense that you seem to understand) a server is just a computer with a file system showing you files; similar to other computers.

Comment: @AbdulAhmad I know that, but the file I want to read is not on my computer. It is on Google's server. It is stored in my Google Drive and I have the link for the file. I just need a way to read the contents now.

Comment: Maybe let the user enter the url to the file in a textbox, and then your web server can connect to it and download it in the server-side code?

Comment: @NamelessOne For my purposes, that doesn't work. I am creating a website and right now I am coding the registration part. I am trying to read a file on my Google Drive to confirm that the user is not trying to create an account that already exists.

Comment: Then you need to connect via some Google Drive API.

Comment: @NamelessOne do you know of way I can import the Google Apps Script classes into my javascript or html? That would be my ideal solution because I will eventually have to write to files also.

Comment: Please don't do the registration/security in javascript, that stuff belongs on the web server so that you have control over it and can rely on it. Please read up on "cross site scripting" if you don't understand why.

Comment: @NamelessOne I am using a .asp file for security. But I used the `<%@ language="javascript"%>` at the top of the file because I am better with javascript than I am with asp. Is there a reason I shouldn't do this?

Comment: As I said: please read up on "cross site scripting" if you don't understand why. Right now I have to go get some sleep.

Answer (score 0):

In short: no. The file input is something that allows users to select a file, so that browsers can make it available to JavaScript on the page. You would not use it to read a file on a web server. The input does not display the contents on the file on the screen, even when one is selected.

To do that, you can request the file from JavaScript. If it is on Google, you can use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/)

Comment: Is it possible to use this on a website outside of Google Apps Script?